# Storing user music playlists for a website

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

I want to make a music playing website where users can save playlists of songs to be regenerated later. I'm kind of a newbie to sql, but it seems like databases are meant to hold fixed-length variables, whereas a user-generated playlist would be an arbitrary length. There are a couple ways I've thought of to handle this:

- Separate tables (maybe another table for each playlist? )
- XML

I feel like there's an easy third way I'm missing. I'm doing this in php, but if there's a super easy way using django I'd also be interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 tables:

1. Playlists. Fields: id | title | owner_id (reference to user.id)
2. Songs. Fields: id | title | length | playlist_id (reference to playlist.id)

Comment: What if a song is in more than 1 playlist? Does it go into the database twice?

Comment: @shelman: it depends on your requirements. You can implement either scenario.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
Playlists: list_id|title|owner_id
Songs: song_id|title|artist|album|year|length|style|whatevereelseyouwnattoadd
Songs_In_Lists: song_id|list_id
```

Third table just ties songs to playlists.
otherwise there will be a lot of redundancy with song info if song goes to multiple playlists.
The primary key for the third table will be on both columns. Same song goes to same list only once, so it works fine.

Comment: Having the extra table that was missed in the accepted answer would save a heck of a lot of redundant data.

Comment: And if I want to allow the song to go to the same playlist multiple times, should I just not set `list_id` as a primary key?